# How to match keys in a list and find there intersecting values?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, set

i have a dictionary with lists and my goal is to match a query list against the dictionary and for matched terms display there intersecting values. For example

```
  dict= [(this, ['1']), (word, ['1', '2']), (search, ['2'])]
  searchedQuery = [this, word]

  output = 1
```

Can someone show me the simplest approach in implementing this techniques, i was thinking of using this approach

```
for key in dict.keys():
     ...get values 
     ...intersect values
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
>>> d
[('this', ['1']), ('word', ['1', '2']), ('search', ['2'])]
>>> set.intersection(*[set(v) for k,v in d if k in searchedQuery])
set(['1'])
```

Explanation:

- `for k,v in d if k in searchedQuery` enumerates the pairs in `d` that have the keys you want
- `[set(v) ...]` makes sets of the values
- `*` in front of the list comprehension unpacks the list so we can pass to `set.intersection`
- `set.intersection` gives you the intersection.

Asides:

- As mentioned in another answer, a list of pairs is not really a `dict`.
- It's considered not a good idea to use `dict` for your own variable name (but we see what you mean).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
>>> dic = dict([('this', ['1']), ('word', ['1', '2']), ('search', ['2'])])
>>> searchedQuery = ['this', 'word']
>>> [y for x,y in dic.items() if x in searchedQuery]
[['1'], ['1', '2']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly the same. But there are few things you need to understand before getting into it.

A dictionary in Python, looks something like this

```
d = {'this': ['1'], 'search': ['2'], 'word': ['1', '2']}
```

So, in order to get the data you presented in the form of a dictionary you need to do something like this

```
d = [('this', ['1']), ('word', ['1', '2']), ('search', ['2'])]
print dict(item for item in d)
```

And then you can get the values from the dictionaries, corresponding to the `searchedQuery` and  finally do the set intersection like this

```
print set.intersection(*[set(d.get(item, {})) for item in searchedQuery])
# set(['1'])
```